# Groovy small text manipulation

Tags: groovy

I have the following string:

```
[bla.FormatException, 96][bla, 22][ResourceNotFoundException, 48]
```

i need to make it look like this:

```
['bla.FormatException', 96],
['bla', 22],
['ResourceNotFoundException', 48]
```

right now im doing this:

```
textToAdd.replace("][","],\n[").replace("[","['").replace(", ","', ")
```

it works but it looks amatur and could break if a small change would take place even extra space..
can i use regex for manipulation to make more clear?

Comment: Why do you have to do this? How would `bla bla` be encoded there? Can you 100% rule out, that something upstream not giving you a `.toString()` of some data structure? `.toString()` is unsuitable to serialize data. Use JSON or whatever fits.

Comment: Not sure i understand what youre asking here. but the data comes in as an array as i written above, i need to convert it to string that looks like the result

Comment: This is what i am asking: your input is *highly* suspicious for wrongly
"toString()`ing the real data.  This smells of X-Y-problem and you might
waste time solving the wrong problem.

Comment: Where's the original string coming from? If possible it might be easier to make that output a more standard format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex and multiple assignment are here to help:

```
String text = '[bla.FormatException, 96][bla, 22][ResourceNotFoundException, 48]'

String result = ( text =~ /(\[([^,\[\]]+), (\d+)\])/ ).findAll().collect{ _, __, name, number -> "['$name', $number]" }.join( ',\n' )

assert result == '''\
['bla.FormatException', 96],
['bla', 22],
['ResourceNotFoundException', 48]'''
```